# Python/Flask query returning empty table with correct number of cells

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, pymysql

I'm doing this python flask project.

When I'm executing a query, the resulting webpage shows the resulting table with the correct number of rows and columns and cells but all the cells are empty.

[removed code]

Comment: 1) `SELECT * ...` is not a good idea. The output of `*`  can change under you. 2) What does `pymysql.cursors.DictCursor` actually return? Is it like in `psycopg2` where it can be accessed via indexing or via keys? 3) Is `cursor.fetchall()` actually returning anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By requesting `DictCursor` as you are, it seems the results should be coming as dicts keyed by table column names, as in the test cases at the top of the file here: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/main/pymysql/tests/test_DictCursor.py

In that case you need to change your accessors from indexes to column names, e.g. `{{item[0]}}` to `{{item['colname']}}`.

Comment: Thank you! I used some starter code without realizing exactly what it was doing